# Merging date in SQL request?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

This is the context : I want to get the average content of two reserves on each day. They are recorded a few times a day and inserted in the db in event_param column. It's possible that some day the second reserve is not used. Therefore we don't have data on the reserve content. And this is the problem.

I give you the table structure on which I am doing the query :

[image]

And This is my query :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT cast(event_datetime as date) as day, event_param_2 as R1, AVG(event_param_3) as ContentR1
FROM events
WHERE upcNameId = 'Name'
AND event_datetime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
AND event_datetime <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
AND event_code IN(52,53,54)
AND event_param_2 = 1  
GROUP BY cast(event_datetime as date)
ORDER BY cast(event_datetime as date)asc) as r1reservecontent,
(SELECT cast(event_datetime as date) as day, event_param_2 as R2, AVG(event_param_3) as ContentR2
FROM events
WHERE upcNameId = 'Name'
AND event_datetime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
AND event_datetime <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
AND event_code IN(52,53,54)
AND event_param_2 = 2
GROUP BY cast(event_datetime as date)
ORDER BY cast(event_datetime as date)asc)as r2reservecontent
```

As you can see I group and to the average on each day for each reserve.
The result is here :
[image]

But this is not what I want. I would like to have only **one** Day column with the content separated for each day.
The days where R1 or R2 is not given it would be equal to the last content recorded.

I know it is a complex problem and it is hard to solve when you have just this informations but it would be nice if you could help me please.

[image]

This is some sample data from the table events.
event_param_2 = number of the reserve (=1 or 2)
event_param_3 = content in kg

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Comment: What do you mean by sample data ? I gave the structure, the query and the result I don't know what else I can give

Comment: Either see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - or just sit around and wait for Gordon to do it all for you, which seems easier.

Comment: I added sample data hope it helps.

Comment: It's best to avoid using images to present important parts of your question. Why? For one thing, images can't be searched, making it harder for others to benefit from your question. For another, sometimes people answering questions like to try to run your queries on their own machines or in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing a sql stored procedure